# Is <table> semantic for displaying phone, email, and fax?

Tags: html, html-table, semantic-web, semantic-markup

Is the following [code](http://jsbin.com/adigas/1/edit) semantic use of [HTML tables?](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <td>+1234567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <td><a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <td>+1234568</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Unformatted, it will look like this:

[image]

Seems to be tabular data to me. (Thus, not only done for layout — although a side-effect is that it helps for having equal columns.)

Comment: I'd use a definition list for that

Comment: @OneTrickPony exactly, but why didn't you answer? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are putting your contact into `<table>` solely for layout purposes, then you'd do better to use css styled `<dl>`.  The identifiers would go in `<dt>`s and the data in `<dd>`s.

But if you are actually outputting a table of several contacts, then `<table>` would be the correct element to use.  Don't forget to use `<th>`s for the identifiers and `<td>`s for the data.

Comment: Great answer, [most](http://css-tricks.com/utilizing-the-underused-but-semantically-awesome-definition-list/) of [the](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/) other [stuff](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/qt/uses-for-definition-lists.htm) seems to agree

Comment: make it more semantic, mark it up with microformats, rdfa, or microdata

Answer (score 4):

There's no black and white answer here, but that is not tabular data.

There is absolutely no reason that contact details would require *equal columns*, that is a purely cosmetical benefit of tables, and is at the discretion of the designer. I would not use tables for that kind of data, I would stick to other elements, and then create equal widths with CSS.

I would define tabular data as data you could expect to see on a spreadsheet.

Comment: Well, using that argument, I could say that people use spreadsheets for all sorts of things: often you see contact details presented there — e.g. if a spreadsheet of competitors, clients, customers, etc.

Comment: And using your argument, you could argue that pretty much any content is tabular. You don't have column headers, you don't have any repeating data, and the content is unrelated. It's simply not tabular data. It's just a bunch of definitions.

Comment: There don't have to be column headers — in this case, I actually meant to use row headers. But on that note, adding the column headers "Medium" and "Details" would show how the content in each column is related.

Comment: @Baumr: A table implies a set of related records. In your case, you have 1 record with a set of related fields in the form of name:value pairs. You could make the argument that each name:value pair is a record, but it's a weak argument because the datatype of the values varies.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, it seems you are getting a little worked up about this. Consider toning down your accusations: I am not trying to "twist [your] answer", nor am I trying to "make [you] change your answer" (although the latter is encouraged on StackOverflow). Perhaps I could have been clearer: I am playing Devil's advocate asking you most of this.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, on that note, I used 'Details' only as an example — I was looking for a word to use instead of 'John Smith's Contact IDs' or 'All Contact Details of This Person/Company'. I disagree, the data in each field is not "completely unrelated" at all — it relates to a single entity, e.g. John Smith, thus it is related. It is distinctly different from what's in the first of each row column; or if one were to put Jenny May's contact details in there.

Comment: @dnagirl, you're right — and I agree with you, but it's also worth considering [some suggested uses](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm), one that particularly stands out: **"If the contents makes sense in a database, especially a very simple database, and you just want to display the data, and not "make it pretty", then a table is acceptable."**

Comment: @Baumr: I can't say I agree with that suggested use.

Comment: @dnagirl, to each their own — but thank you, I'll actually be using `dl` in this case [as you suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461523/1779823) because it'll give me more control via CSS. Though I just saw another suggested use in that article: **"If you're going to have header fields at the top of columns of data or to the left of rows of data, then it is tabular and a table should be used."**